# Neo4j cypher queries slow to 70ms from 6ms intermittently

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Problem

I have a neo4j database whose data is replaced hourly via CSV import. After importing there are `6` distinct node types, `5` indexes, and `1042` total nodes.
Sometimes after this CSV import runs (maybe 1/30 imports) neo4j slows significantly. When this happens, we simply rerun the csv import and neo4j becomes fast again.

Here's a profile of a Match query **during slowness**:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And here is *the same* profile after simply rerunning my csv import with *the same data*:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Lastly, here's what our new relic monitoring shows for neo4j query time for 45 minutes before we rerun the import:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

### Question

What could be causing this slowness? What can we do to avoid it?

### Some things I've checked / tried

- I've compared the raw csv values with the resulting data, the number of nodes is the same during slowness as it is after and it matches the number of nodes in the csvs
- All 5 indexes are created during and after slowness

EDIT:
**Here's the debug log during one of these slowdowns**:

````
2019-12-19 01:30:44.134+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 7186 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {hostName: $hn})
return c.id
2019-12-19 01:30:44.149+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 2814 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {id: $key})
       -[gr]-(a:Ag)
       -[ar]-(ad:Ad)
       -[fr]-(ff:Ff)
       -[sr]-(sp:Sp)
  WHERE sp.id IN $sps
  AND (:Cu)-[:HAS_AG]-(a)
  AND NOT ()-[:HAS_FILL_AG]->(a)
  AND ad.act = true
  AND ad.eD > datetime()
  AND ad.sD < datetime()
//AND a.eD > datetime()
//AND a.sD < datetime()
with distinct ad, sp, c, ff, a
RETURN ad.id, ad.nm, ad.iag, ad.ual, ad.ml, sp.id, c.hN as hn, c.spl as spl, ff.width, ff.height, a.isHq
2019-12-19 01:30:45.524+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 8236 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {id: $key})
       -[gr]-(a:Ag)
       -[ar]-(ad:Ad)
       -[fr]-(ff:Ff)
       -[sr]-(sp:Sp)
  WHERE sp.id IN $sps
  AND (:Cu)-[:HAS_AG]-(a)
  AND NOT ()-[:HAS_FILL_AG]->(a)
  AND ad.act = true
  AND ad.eD > datetime()
  AND ad.sD < datetime()
//AND a.eD > datetime()
//AND a.sD < datetime()
with distinct ad, sp, c, ff, a
RETURN ad.id, ad.nm, ad.iag, ad.ual, ad.ml, sp.id, c.hN as hn, c.spl as spl, ff.width, ff.height, a.isHq
2019-12-19 01:30:51.880+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Scheduled checkpoint for time threshold" @ txId: 20253 checkpoint started...
2019-12-19 01:30:51.895+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Rotated counts store at transaction 20253 to [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a], from [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b].
2019-12-19 01:30:51.912+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Scheduled checkpoint for time threshold" @ txId: 20253 checkpoint completed in 31ms
2019-12-19 01:30:51.912+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] No log version pruned, last checkpoint was made in version 21
2019-12-19 01:30:54.886+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 10 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {hostName: $hn})
return c.id
2019-12-19 01:38:29.422+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 464 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {id: $key})
       -[gr]-(a:Ag)
       -[ar]-(ad:Ad)
       -[fr]-(ff:Ff)
       -[sr]-(sp:Sp)
  WHERE sp.id IN $sps
  AND (:Cu)-[:HAS_AG]-(a)
  AND NOT ()-[:HAS_FILL_AG]->(a)
  AND ad.act = true
  AND ad.eD > datetime()
  AND ad.sD < datetime()
//AND a.eD > datetime()
//AND a.sD < datetime()
with distinct ad, sp, c, ff, a
RETURN ad.id, ad.nm, ad.iag, ad.ual, ad.ml, sp.id, c.hN as hn, c.spl as spl, ff.width, ff.height, a.isHq
2019-12-19 01:47:42.049+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.DefaultBoltConnection] The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
2019-12-19 01:47:42.585+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.DefaultBoltConnection] The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
2019-12-19 02:04:05.996+0000 INFO [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache after 2000 seconds: MATCH(c:Ch {id: $key})
       -[gr]-(a:Ag)
       -[ar]-(ad:Ad)
       -[fr]-(ff:Ff)
       -[sr]-(sp:Sp)
  WHERE sp.id IN $sps
  AND (:Cu)-[:HAS_AG]-(a)
  AND NOT ()-[:HAS_FILL_AG]->(a)
  AND ad.act = true
  AND ad.eD > datetime()
  AND ad.sD < datetime()
//AND a.eD > datetime()
//AND a.sD < datetime()
with distinct ad, sp, c, ff, a
RETURN ad.id, ad.nm, ad.iag, ad.ual, ad.ml, sp.id, c.hN as hn, c.spl as spl, ff.width, ff.height, a.isHq
2019-12-19 02:04:11.967+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Scheduled checkpoint for time threshold" @ txId: 20260 checkpoint started...
2019-12-19 02:04:11.984+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Rotated counts store at transaction 20260 to [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2019-12-19 02:04:12.010+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Scheduled checkpoint for time threshold" @ txId: 20260 checkpoint completed in 43ms
2019-12-19 02:04:12.011+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] No log version pruned, last checkpoint was made in version 21```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ0q4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMlai.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2cAM.png
````

Comment: Is _every query_ slow after those slowness-inducing imports? Not just the first few queries, but any `MATCH` you do is slower to the tune of 70ms?

Comment: @Pablissimo I'd have to go back and profile more queries, but yes the 70ms profile is after this query has run many times. New relic monitoring shows that the slow down is consistent for the full hour until the next import rolls around on cron

Comment: I've edited my post to add a graph from newrelic that shows this

Comment: can you share the debug.log of slow period ?

Comment: @logisima I've updated my question to include the debug.log for the relevant time period